# Regular Expression to extract in parantheses values java

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract the values of the string that looks like this:

```
nameClass (val1)(val2)
```

to have:

```
nameClass
val1
val2
```

The problem is that it must also be applicable to this:

```
nameClass
```

and

```
nameClass (val1)(val2)(val1)...(valn)
```

I tried to create the regex but it fits only for the

```
nameClass (val1)(val2)
```

variant and looks like this (after being improved by **Viorel Moraru**):

```
String pattern = "((?:[a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]+))(([ |(]+)([-|+]?\\d+)([ |(|)]+)([-|+]?\\d+)([ |)]+))*";
```

How do I make the pattern to be applicable to all

```
nameClass
```

and

```
nameClass (val1)(val2)(val1)...(valn)
```

?

Java Code:

```js
String txt = "inputTestdata(12)(-13)";
String patern = "((?:[a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]+))([ |(]+)([-|+]?\\d+)([ |(|)]+)([-|+]?\\d+)([ |)]+)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
if (m.find())
{
  for (int i = 1; i < m.groupCount(); i ++)
  {
   System.out.print(m.group(i) + "\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Can brackets be nested also?

Comment: No, just one after another

Comment: do you really need a regex for this? what about traversing the string and extracting substrings out?

Comment: assuming that the initial string would increase in complexity it is preferably to use regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
String s = "nameClass(val1)(val2)(val3)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+) *(.*)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
String ps = "";
if (m.matches())
{
  ps = m.group(2);
  System.out.printf("Outside parantheses:<%s>\n", m.group(1));
}
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]*)\\)");
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(ps);
while (m1.find())
{
  System.out.printf("Inside parentheses:<%s>%n", m1.group(1));
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Outside parantheses:<nameClass>
Inside parentheses:<val1>
Inside parentheses:<val2>
Inside parentheses:<val3>
```

Comment: This code does not work for all cases:
"nameClass", "nameClass (var1)", "nameClass (var1) (var2)", "nameClass (var1) (var2)(var4) (var5)"

Comment: Can you provide some inputs that are not working with this answer?

Comment: if you have for instance just "nameClass" string.
but with a small fix you can get it running 

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+) *(.*)$");

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that:

- Your input does not need to be validated insofar as it starts with
  `nameClass`
- You want to sanitize the parenthesis (as your question currently leads me to understand)

... why don't you just replace everything between parenthesis with its content?

For instance:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((.+?)\\)");
String[] inputs = {"nameClass", "nameClass (var1)", "nameClass (var1) (var2)"};
Matcher m;
for (String input: inputs) {
    m = p.matcher(input);
    System.out.println("Input: " + input + " --> replacement: " + m.replaceAll("$1"));
    // resetting matcher after "replaceAll" and accessing values directly by group 1 reference
    m.reset();
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("\tFound value: " + m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Input: nameClass --> replacement: nameClass
Input: nameClass (var1) --> replacement: nameClass var1
    Found value: var1
Input: nameClass (var1) (var2) --> replacement: nameClass var1 var2
    Found value: var1
    Found value: var2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no regex expert but does this work?

```
\s*\w+\s*(\(\w+\))*
```